# why can i not see "build a user interface" in Google app script file menu?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can see the "build a user interface" option in Google app script file menu?  I have come across questions where it is there, but greyed out.  I can see anthing at all.

I trully hope I'm not being stupid here or asking a question that has been answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you talk about the GUI builder that was a graphic User Interface Builder.  I has been deprecated a long time ago and although the apps created with it are still working there is no way to create / modify UI using this tool.

You can find a lot of post mentioning it here on SO but you can't use it anymore.

Comment: Yes that is what I was referring to.  I saw a tutorial on Youtube where I can across it.  It was a few years old.  Thanks for the response.

Seemed like a handy addon, it's a petty it was removed.

Comment: It worked nicely indeed... I used it a lot and I don't really know why they removed it but the new tools like HTML service are so much more powerful (but not as simple, I admit :-)

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is deprecated, visit the https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset to be updated